# d3.js - Check parentNode value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to check if a parent node equals a certain type as defined in the JSON data. Using d3.js v4 (yes I know...)

For example in the JSON:

```
{"name":"ABC", "type":"3program_outcome_group","children":[{"name":"XY","type":"program_outcome"},...
```

In this example, I want to check if parent node's type ('type' being a custom parameter) is equal to `3program_outcome_group`.  At the same time, I also need to check if the child node is of type `program_outcome`.

I have tried:

```
if (d.type == 'program_outcome' && d.parentNode.type == '3program_outcome_group' )
    return d.name.substring(0, 6);
```

But it's not working...

Whereas the following works without checking the parentNode:

```
if (d.type == 'program_outcome')
     return d.name.substring(0, 4);
```

I have also tried:

```
if (d.type == 'program_outcome' && this.parentNode.type == '3program_outcome_group' )
       return d.name.substring(0, 6);
```

Comment: Is the question in the context of a certain layout e.g. tree, network etc ?

Comment: dendrogram hierarchical tree...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I used the following which works to find the parent node's value for the custom 'type' parameter:

```
if (d.type == 'program_outcome' && d.parent.type == '3program_outcome_group')
                    //do something
```